# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dash_extensions.callback'

Tags: python, plotly-dash

since I am using anaconda, so I installed dash_extensions using below command instead of pip.

conda install -c conda-forge dash-extensions

https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/dash-extensions

I can import dash_extensions and no problem. Just import dash_extensions.callback is not working.  Do I have to use pip install? I am concerned it will create some issues if I use pip install inside anaconda.

Thanks for help.

the pip install is here, but I didn't use it

pip install dash-extensions

https://pypi.org/project/dash-extensions/

```
from dash_extensions.callback import CallbackCache, Trigger

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_33592/2123918533.py in 
----> 1 from dash_extensions.callback import CallbackCache, Trigger

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dash_extensions.callback'
```

Comment: So you're trying to import something, and you got an error because it isn't there. Let's ask the obvious question -- is that import actually correct?  Is `dash_extensions.callback` something that _should_ be importable?  Where, exactly, did you get that line of code from?  Are you following some example?

Comment: Thanks John. Yes, I am following the example here, https://community.plotly.com/t/show-and-tell-server-side-caching/42854/97